# Updated to kernel 4.8.4-wifi no longer connects

Tags: wireless

I'm very very new to Linux. I downloaded and installed the new kernel, 4.8.4, and now my wifi just shows "enable networking" but doesn't connect to anything. I'm not sure what to do

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Remove the unsupported kernel and wifi will start working again ;-) Questions about problems with unsupported kernels are off-topic.

Comment: I typed into the command line what this guy said: http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/10/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-8-4-in-linux.html?m=1

Comment: Did you blacklist acer-wmi after the kernel update?

Comment: I'm sorry for being off topic. I really don't know how to get the wifi going again. There's just no list of networks available. My Broadcom is still installed

Comment: I don't know what that means Patrick

Comment: This is my Broadcom.     14e4:4365 rev 01

Comment: @Pilot6 Does he have to remove the 4.8.4 kernel or simply reboot with an older version like 4.4.0-45?

Answer (score 1):

Installing unsupported kernel is generally not good idea (except you need some specific fix which is implemented there).

Now, to get your wifi working again, you should remove this new kernel. Open terminal and type:

`sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-4.8.4... #(press <kbd>tab</kbd> to autocomplete)`

`sudo apt-get autoremove linux-headers-4.8.4... #(press <kbd>tab</kbd> again)`

and last but very very important

`sudo update-grub`

Now reboot, your old kernel will be back (if you haven't **removed** it meanwhile, in that case, you will need to download and install old kernel manually.)

**EDIT**

How to install older kernel:
Download these files:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.14-xenial/linux-headers-4.4.14-040414_4.4.14-040414.201606241434_all.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.14-xenial/linux-headers-4.4.14-040414-generic_4.4.14-040414.201606241434_amd64.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.14-xenial/linux-image-4.4.14-040414-generic_4.4.14-040414.201606241434_amd64.deb

and install them in order: headers - all, headers, image

Comment: `update-grub` is not needed. It will be run automatically, unless OP installed a kernel without using deb packages. But then your whole answer is not relevant.

Comment: I did remove my old kernel. How do I go about downloading the old one again?

Comment: What is your operating system? Is it Ubuntu?

Comment: At least I think I did. I'm really frustrated and really don't want to have to go back to windows.

Comment: Yes it is. Ubuntu 16.05 LTS

Comment: You can always re-install the system if you are "frustrated" and never install unsupported kernels until you know how to uninstall them.

Comment: Give me few seconds, I'll update my answer with steps needed to install older kernel.

Comment: I meant 16.04 LTS. How do I reinstall everything

Comment: Ok Michal, I've installed the files just like you've said. What do I do now?

Comment: I checked the kernel and it says 4.4.14.

Comment: after reboot it should work

Comment: I've rebooted into and it worked. The wifi driver still isn't there

Comment: Ok, download also image-extra. Just use provided links and delete the last part. From there download the mentioned image and install it.

Comment: I've tried every combination and I can't figure it out.

Comment: My bad, there are no extra packages. If it still isn't working, I recommend reinstall. You must have changed something specific. If you have separated / (root) and /home partition, you can preserve your data during reinstall.